# Editing file in zip using Truezip is creating a tmp file, but not editing the file inside zip

Tags: edit, zip, truezip

I want to edit a file "application.properties" inside "imp" directory inside a zip "archive.zip". I'm using Truezip for this. I tried using both TFileOutputStream and  TFileWriter. But both of them are creating a **tmp** file, but not editing the actual file in zip. The actual file in zip still remains same. Below are my code samples:
1. Using TFileOutputStream:

```
    OutputStream out = new TFileOutputStream("C:\sample\archive.zip\imp\application.properties");
    // Loading properties code here
    properties.store(out, null);
    out.close();
```

2. Using TFileWriter:

> ```
> File entry = new TFile("C:\sample\archive.zip\imp\application.properties");
> Writer writer = new TFileWriter(entry);
> try {
>     writer.write("wish.world=Hello world\n");
> } finally {
>     writer.close();
> }
> ```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `TVFS.umount()` to persist your changes.

Comment: This worked. But inside the zip, the things that got edited are going as a separate folder. Instead, apart from the file getting edited I don't want another folder to be created. Right now my zip has two folders instead of one. Please help

Comment: Check the `TConfig` class. You need to clear the `FsOutputOption.CREATE_PARENTS`.